# Empty XML node rendered as string in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I read an xml file with an empty node, let's say `<mynode/>`. When reading the node with something like `$myfile.foo.bar.mynode` the returned type is string and passing this to a function that expects type [Xml.XmlElement], it fails saying that string cannot be converted to XmlElement.

One solution could be to write

```
$myfile.foo.bar.selectsinglenode('mynode')
```

but I'm wondering why string is returned in the first example and if there is a shorter solution than using `SelectSingleNode()`

Comment: I don't think there's a shorter solution. `$myx.foo.bar.ChildNodes.Item(0)`. Reason is that the dot notation returns the contents of the node - in your case nothing, so an empty string

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the empty string reason !

Comment: It's quite unscientific, but I'll gladly add it as an answer if you understand the implication